# Geodesics, exponential map and implicit function theorem

Tags: geometry

I am a bored guy trying to have some fun with math.

I define a $m$ dimensional surface $\mathcal{X}$, if you may a submanifold, as the graph of the implicit equality $f(x) = 0$, $f \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(X)$, for every coordinate $x$ within set $X \cap \mathbb{D}_f$, the former a vector field of inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle^X$ and basis $B_X$ and the latter corresponding to domain of function $f$. We may directly define its tangent vector space $T_x \mathcal{X}$, given by the null space ker$(\nabla^\intercal \,f)$.

Implicit  function theorem assures the existence of a (local, hopefully global) diffeomorphic map $\psi$ such that there is a neighborhood $B \subset X$ of coordinate $x$ to every coordinate $y$ in the intersection set $B \cap \mathbb{D}_f \cap \mathcal{X}$ such that $x = \psi(u)$, for some coordinate $u$ of dimension $n-m$ and defined-to-be space $\mathcal{U}$.

In fact, the geodesic curve $\gamma: [0, 1] \times T_x \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}$, connecting $x$ and $y$ ALMOST performs this task, except for a additional dimension due parametrization coordinate $s$ along the curve.

My question is: what is the relation between the geodesic curve $\gamma(s, u)$ and implicit function $\psi(v)$? Both coordinates $u$ and $v$ exhibit dimension $n-m$.